# printing prime number with checking remainder by dividing 2 OR 3

Tags: java, oop

i am new to java , i tried to print prime number with my own logic.
to check prime number i will devide given input number with number 2 and 3
if remainder is 0 witg AND condition then its a prime else not a prime.

but problem is---
for any key stroke input its printing as prime,   in a iteration
please analyze and tell me what i did wrong in logic

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter the number");
    double j=r.nextDouble();
    double k =j%2;
    double f =j%3;


    if(k==0 && f==0)
    {
        System.out.println("its not prime number");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("its  a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using the modulo operator. is that your intent?

Comment: Check your prime logic .. its not correct. Input `6` it will give not prime

Comment: @Sanjeev `6` isn't a prime number

Comment: Primes are integers. Use integer type (like `int` or `long`) and not `double`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen i know that i am just talking about OPs implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch:

```
if(k==0 && f==0)
```

to

```
if(k==0 || f==0)
```

as it only needs to fulfill one to be not prime.

Comment: and also check every other number in `[2, sqrt(n)]`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen very true there are more issues, but I figured they understood that logic was not absolute.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen only check for every positive prime number less than sqrt(n) (assuming 1 isnt a prime number)

Comment: @Wietlol `[2, sqrt(n)]` *is* every positive number <= `sqrt(n)` not including 1.

Comment: I also said **prime**. if your number is divisible by N where N is divisible by  X, then checking for only X is enough... for example, why check if it is divisible by 4 if it is not divisible by 2? The only problem now is, that you require a sorted list of all prime numbers less than sqrt(n)

Comment: @jorge tnks it works....but this logic is not applying for input number 1 or 2, for other number it works

Comment: @shreyas Just to be sure, I want to point out that there are composite numbers that are not divisible by 2 and 3.  Like 91 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's several errors:

1. Don't mix INTEGERS and DOUBLES at compare statments. Change double to int/long.
2. Your logic is bad:

> ```
> double k=j%2;
> double k=j%3;
> if(k==0 && f==0) {...}
> ```
>
> 2 can exactly divide any pair number and 3 can exactly divide almost
>   all odd numbers. Because && operator they'll differ almost every time.

3. Your logic is bad. Even if you change && by || operator.

May be you must use the classic logic: A prime number is a number that only can be divided by itlsef and the unit. This logic is well known, easy to read and understand (is the standard).